# Golang cannot compile wasmer

Tags: go, webassembly, wasi

Am trying to build a simple go file, with the following contents:

```
package main

import (
    _ "embed"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/mattn/gowasmer"
)

//go:embed main.wasm
var webassembly []byte

func main() {
    inst, err := gowasmer.NewInstance(webassembly)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    m := inst.Get("fn")
    r := m.(func([]interface{}) interface{})([]interface{}{1, 3})
    fmt.Printf("1 + 3 = %v\n", r)
}
```

However, I keep getting the following linker error:

```
PS C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\wasi> wasmer --version
wasmer 4.0.0
PS C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\wasi> go run .        
# github.com/wasmerio/wasmer-go/wasmer
..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\wasmerio\wasmer-go@v1.0.4\wasmer\wasi.go: In function 'to_wasi_env_read_inner':
..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\wasmerio\wasmer-go@v1.0.4\wasmer\wasi.go:23:22: warning: implicit declaration of function 'open_memstream' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   23 | //     memory_stream = open_memstream(buffer, &buffer_size);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\wasmerio\wasmer-go@v1.0.4\wasmer\wasi.go:23:20: warning: assignment to 'FILE *' {aka 'struct _iobuf *'} from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]     
   23 | //     memory_stream = open_memstream(buffer, &buffer_size);
      |                    ^
# main
C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwasmer: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any clues on how to fix this error? Cannot really find anything looking it up.